# Hit a URL in JAVA without redirecting

Tags: java, php, redirect

I want to hit a URL in php from java servlet.I just want to send a information to that url.I didn't need to go to that url.i want to stay in my page.Anyway to do that.?

Comment: httpComponents maybe? http://hc.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

You could simply make a post on that url like in the http components [doc](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/post.html)

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://jakarata.apache.org/");
NameValuePair[] data = {
      new NameValuePair("user", "joe"),
      new NameValuePair("password", "bloggs")
};
post.setRequestBody(data);
// execute method and handle any error responses.
...
InputStream in = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
// handle response.
```

Comment: Apache Http Client is in version 4 already. Using version 3 is not recommended (but yes, it works).

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
            URL url = new URL("your url");

            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000); // time out
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
            String postData = "your post data";
            out.print(postData);
            out.close();
            String response  connection.getInputStream();
```

or you can use

```
           Request.Post("your url").bodyForm(
                Form.form().add("parameter name", "value")
                .add("parameter name1", "value").build()).execute();
```